# NotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)) occurs only when I use https url, working fine for same url http

Tags: java, json, spring, http, sap-commerce-cloud

```
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
     at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]

    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:916)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:636)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:598)
    at de.portaltech.vorward.amsys.client.impl.DefaultAmsysRestClient.retrieveAdvisorByAddress(DefaultAmsysRestClient.java:96)
    at de.portaltech.vorward.amsys.client.impl.DefaultAmsysRestClientUnitTest.testRetrieveAdvisorByAddress(DefaultAmsysRestClientUnitTest.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2630)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:237)
    ... 32 more
```

I got this exception when I perform

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", authValue);
headers.add("user-agent", "");
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
RequestEntity requestEntity = new RequestEntity(headers, HttpMethod.GET, new 
URI("https://universities-plo8-r.domain.net/api/public/find_uni_by_address/param1/param2? 
street=Brunnenstrasse&streetNo=22&postcode=011210&city=Berlin&maxCount=100"));
final ResponseEntity<AAResultData[]> response = getRestTemplate().exchange(request, 
AAResultData[].class);
```

> - If I do exactly the same thing with only one difference (to remove the s from the url) using same url but http://unive.... it works fine
>     and I got the expected result.
> - The request works fine with both http & https on Postman!

Please help if you have any idea ;) Thanks

Comment: Have you tried logging the actual contents of the response from within your application? Other tools might yield different results, so Postman might get a different result than your application (due to different settings and/or error-handling)...

Comment: Thanks Nicktar for your comment, but yeah, that was also my thought to make my app config as similar as possible to the postman-config. The problem unfortunately remains

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you were not certificated while using HTTPS so that you got an error page in HTML format (such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`...) rather than a normal and valid JSON one.

Please ensure that you have already installed a valid SSL certificate for the target endpoint while visiting it with HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, but how do you explain that the same service is working via POSTMAN?